# es6 javascript arrow function

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

The following is the code on react:

```
  handleChange = name => event => {
    console.log(name, event.target.value);
  }
```

And here is the code on the react DOM

```
onChange={this.handleChange('storeName')}
```

What i do not understand is, how did the event got passed in without even declaring it in the this.handleChange('storeName') function ??how does it work ? Because i thought usually it works like this.

```
this.handleChange(e)
```

and then you try to get the event by declaring it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
handleChange = name => event => {
```

Is not a simple function. It's a function that returns a function. Let's rewrite a bit:

```
function name => {
   return event => {
       // name is captured inside this closure
       console.log(name, event.target.value);
   }
}
```

Therefore the call `this.handleChange('storeName')` actually generates a function that takes an `event` as a parameter and we then assign *that* function to `onChange`.

Answer (score 2):

Because `this.handleChange('storeName')` returns a function which is then assigned to `onChange` handler.